# Building a one week calendar / schedule

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

My website involves scheduling recurring lessons and events.  At present I have built a table using php and javascript which scans through my mysql DB, time slot by timeslot, day by day to see if there is an event scheduled or if the timeslot is free.

It works fine, but is quite clunky and ugly and to be honest, not user friendly enough.  I have now built the rest of the site using JQuery along with php, JS, HTML.

I have searched far and wide for a JQuery module to sort me out for this, but every calendar/scheduler I find is for ongoing time, i.e. like the Outlook Calendar.

I want one that ONLY displays Monday - Sunday, with time intervals of a half hour - what's the best way for me to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance,
Brett

Comment: Are you asking about the client-side, server-side implementation or both?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  All appointments are stored on my MySQL DB, whatever method I implement will retrieve and update the relevant tables there.  I am really asking about the front end implementation, the backend infrastructure is already there, I'm just looking for a user friendly way to present it, ideally involding being able to click on one or more times and creating an appointment in that/those timeslot/s in an easy, user friendly way.  Thanks, B

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a control that you can stick on your page, to which you could save down to your DB?

Comment: Yes.  The user would open the schedule page and all of their current appointments (from the DB) would be displayed in the relevant Days / Times.  They would then be able to add/remove/edit appointments which would inert/delete/update on the DB - I'm not looking for any coding help on this, just a possible front end to use for it that is user friendly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

may be this can be of help if you haven checked it out already https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/